# diagonals parallel with the first diagonal in a square matrix

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to get all the diagonals that are parallel with the first diagonal in a square matrix, using python.

```
    matrix = [[1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8],
              [9,0,1,2],
              [3,4,5,6]]

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
       for j in range(len(matrix)):
           diagonal = []
           if i == j + 1 :
                diagonal.append(mat[i][j])
                print(diagonal, end=" ")
```

With my first diagonal:

```
    [1][6][1][6]
```

And the output is:

```
    [5] [0] [5]
```

But i'm looking for both of them:

```
    [5] [0] [5] and 
    [9] [4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) installed you get [diagonals (with offsets)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) for free:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array( [[1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8],
              [9,0,1,2],
              [3,4,5,6]])

print(matrix.diagonal())          # -> [1 6 1 6]
print(matrix.diagonal(offset=-1)) # -> [5 0 5]
print(matrix.diagonal(offset=-2)) # -> [9 4]
```

this is a way to do this by hand:

```
def diagonal(matrix, offset=0):
    ret = []
    l = len(matrix)
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        j = i+offset
        if j < 0:
            continue
        if j >= l:
            break
        ret.append(row[j])
    return ret

print(diagonal(matrix))            # -> [1, 6, 1, 6]
print(diagonal(matrix, offset=-1)) # -> [5, 0, 5]
print(diagonal(matrix, offset=-2)) # -> [9, 4]
```

or a more compact and efficient version that generates the diagonal with a list comprehension:

```
def diagonal(matrix, offset=0):
    dim = len(matrix)
    return [matrix[i][j] for i, j in
            zip(range(-offset if offset < 0 else 0, dim),
                range(offset if offset > 0 else 0, dim))]
```

Comment: i wanted to it without any predefined